# Show that $\sigma(S(C))=\sigma(C)$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ S(C)$ be an algebra generated by $C$ and let $\sigma(S(C))$ be a sigma algebra generated by $ S(C)$. Show that $\sigma(S(C))=\sigma(C)$.

I can show $\sigma(C) \subset \sigma(S(C))$ this is actually very trivial. How about the other direction.

Comment: Can you show that $S(C) \subset \sigma(C)$?

Comment: NO. I was thinking about this. Isn't algebra alway bigger than sigma algebra

Comment: No, every $\sigma$-algebra is in particular an algebra. One where countable unions and intersections don't lead out of the algebra.

Comment: I see. But how would I show that $S(C) \subset \sigma(C)$?

Comment: How are $S(C)$ resp. $\sigma(C)$ characterised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S(C) \subset \sigma(C)$ since $\sigma(C)$ is an algebra containing $C$ and $S(C)$ is the smallest algebra conatining $C$.Then $\sigma(S(C)) \subset \sigma(\sigma(C))=\sigma(C)$

**Explanation of equality:**

if $\cal A$  is a $\sigma-$ algebra then $\sigma(\cal A)=\cal A$

Comment: Yes Daniel! I am sorry and I was not going to give everything if I had seen your last question.

Comment: Lan u ezplain equality after subser

Comment: @Daniel: You are right but I think that  beginners often need further explanation as you see about the last Boby question about equality.

Comment: @Boby:  I just added explanation.

Comment: @Daniel: It was necessary to remove it so. I did. thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you very much.  But I still don't understand the last equality. Why is $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}$. I don't know why I don't see it. Could you give me some intuition maybe a proof? Sorry for being so slow.

Comment: when you have a subset $C$ of $P(E)$ such that $C$ in not yet a $\sigma-$algebra, you have to add a minimum of elements to $C$ using a certain method to get a $\sigma-$algebra.When $C$ is already a $\sigma-$algébra there is nothing to add.

Comment: Sorry, we have been using some much notation. What is C,P and E?

Comment: See the definition of $\sigma-$algebra: Let $E$ a set and $P(E)$ the set of subsets of $E$. A $\sigma-$algebra is a subset $\cal A$ of $P(E)$ such that ...